# mcrypt_decrypt doesn't work after encrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I want to decrypt an encrypted response using mcrypt_decrypt but this doesn't work, so I'm using this snippet of code for test and the response should be "This is a test":

```
// Encryption Algorithm
// the $shared_key and $init_vector are not real
$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
$shared_key = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
$key = pack("H*", $shared_key);
$init_vector = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
$iv = pack("H*", $init_vector);

echo mcrypt_decrypt($cipher_alg, $key, utf8_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(
        $cipher_alg, $key, utf8_encode('This is a test'), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)),     MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

And the response is:

```
æ †,?7÷q†Ý³‚¢gTô1ò‚ù’Ü”®mÀ{ëQS
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `utf8_encode`?!?!?! I'm not surprised this doesn't work.

Comment: Because using this is as I send the request to web service and they give me a response. The problem is decrypting this response.

Comment: That's still no explanation why you're using `utf8_encode` *on an encrypted string*. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: The admin of the web service send to me this php code and if I given a response this should be fine. Without utf9_encode on my code, for the snippet test code works but with my real code the response is still encrypted

Comment: =_=# Let's put it this way: **it works if you remove `utf8_encode`!** http://viper-7.com/batVhk

Comment: Yes, without utf8_encode my test works like you say but with the real response not. Sorry, but I'll try to find out if the response is correct

Comment: So there's your answer why this particular piece of code doesn't work. Why some *similar* piece of code doesn't work in an entirely different situation, nobody here knows without a lot more details.

Comment: Yes and thanks @deceze. Now I'm looking for why the real response doesn't work. This response is a big hexadecimal code which is encrypted using mcrypt_encrypt and then use in the bin2hex php function

Comment: After rebuild the code, this works fine without utf8_encode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are utf8 encoding the encrypted stuff. That way it is modified and can not be decrypted anymore.

```
echo mcrypt_decrypt($cipher_alg, $key, mcrypt_encrypt(
        $cipher_alg, $key, 'This is a test'), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```